# Is it worth curating/maintaing an answer to an on-hold question?

Tags: discussion

I notice this question is "on hold": [Best graphics card brand/ drivers for gaming on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291045/best-graphics-card-brand-drivers-for-gaming-on-ubuntu)

If mods are going to delete it anyway, is it worth spending effort to actively maintain any answers on such a question?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is for you to reword the question (and, if necessary, your answer) so they meet the rules at https://askubuntu.com/help/closed-questions.

Comment: I wouldn't have a clue how to do that. The question is pretty clear: "Which graphics driver works best with Ubuntu?". If the community says it's off-topic, fair enough, but I'm at a loss to see how it differs from any of these (unclosed) questions: http://askubuntu.com/search?q=best